# Need to send request to API every 2 seconds after promise is resolved, runs in finite loop

Tags: jquery, api, promise, settimeout, apiary

I will try my best to explain my problem.

I have javascript Promise, 2 API and setTimeout in action.

```
    $.each(result[1], function(i, coin) {

        var coincalcClass = new coincalculationClass();

        // this method returns a promise.
        var highforMonth = coincalcClass.getHighLowForSpecificDays(coin.mktName, 3);

        setTimeout(function()  {

        highforMonth.then(function (value) {

            var market_name = coin.mktName;
            var bestPrice = value['1'];

                addAlert('BTRX', market_name, bestPrice);
        }
        )
       }, 1000);//time in milliseconds

    });
```

so, in the code, First I have a json value, (50 values) and I am going through each of them. 
I am making some calulations. 
I call getHighLowForSpecificDays() method which returns promise. when the promise is resolved then I get the value and call addAlert() function which is an API POST request.

The problem here is the code works but the API has a rate limit of 1 request per second. I tried using setTimeout but it is not working because in my thinking, the promise are resolved very quickly and .then function is triggered bypassing the setTimeout().

I need help here so that even if all of the 50 promises are resolved with in a second, the addAlert() method should be called once a sec. I have tried using setTimeout out of the $.each iteration, inside the .then ; nothing helps.

Any Help is appriciated ! 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the calls to your API in a queue that fires every 1 second:

```
// Variables holding the timeout id (for cancelling) and queue to process
var queueId;
var q = [];

// This is the "run" function. 
function runQueue() {

  // If the queue has any items on it, then let's process one
  if (q.length > 0) {

    // Pull the first item off the queue (Last in, first out)
    var f = q.shift();

    // Run it as a function (could probably benefit from a 'typeof' check)
    if (typeof f === "function") {
      f();
    }
  }

  // Set this very function to run again in 1s.
  queueId = setTimeout(runQueue, 1000);
}

// Stop the queue processing
function stopQueue() {
  clearTimeout(queueId);
}

// Start the queue .. the actual queue may be empty, but that won't
// bother the process as it will simply set itself up to run again
// in a second
runQueue();

$.each(result[1], function(i, coin) {

    var coincalcClass = new coincalculationClass();

    // this method returns a promise.
    var highforMonth = coincalcClass.getHighLowForSpecificDays(coin.mktName, 3);

    highforMonth.then(function(value) {
        var market_name = coin.mktName;
        var bestPrice = value['1'];
        q.push(function() { 
          addAlert('BTRX', market_name, bestPrice);
        });
    );
});
```

Edit: this really is a quick and dirty implementation of a queue. My personal favorite is [p-queue](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-queue) which implements rate limiting and other nifty features.

Comment: Wow! I just implemented your code and it works! 
Care to explain what is happening in the first part of the code in the **runQueue()**. I have a general understanding but want to hear from the man himself. Maybe you can engrave it in my mind so next time your solution pops up when I get in this kind of situation

Comment: I have added some inline comments. I am glad this works, but the implemenation by @Roamer-1888 is far more feature rich and has the added benefit of not firing the API request less than 1 second after the last API request returned thus ensuring you don't run afoul of the API requirements.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification with the comments you made. 
I looked at @Roamer's code too. It is a bit complicated for me as I am just starting out. Will be sure to dabble with his code when I need to improve my project.

Answer (score 0):

What you appear to need is something that will meter out requests to an API at a *minimum* interval of 1s, in other words :

- if the API responds in under 1s then the next request should be delayed to 1s after the previous request.
- if the API responds in over 1s then the next request may be made immediately.

Here's a generic asynchronous recursor that does just that :

```
function recurseAsync(arr, fn, initialValue, minimumInterval) {
    var index = 0;
    var arr_ = arr.map(function(x) { return x }); // clone array (safety measure)
    function delay(t) {
        return $.Deferred(function(dfrd) {
            setTimeout(dfrd.resolve, t);
        });
    }
    function recurse(previous) {
        return (index < arr_.length) ? 
            $.when(fn(previous, arr_[index++]), delay(minimumInterval)).then(recurse) :
            previous;
    }
    return recurse(initialValue);
}
```

Implementation of the rules is surprisingly simple. The expression `$.when(fn(previous, arr_[index++]), delay(minimumInterval)).then(recurse)` ensures that `recurse` is called only when BOTH the `fn()` call has resolved AND the mimimum delay has happened. It's a strange kind of race, in which the last man home fires the starting pistol for the next race.

Usage for the coincalcClass API:

```
function getCoinData(previous, current) {
    var coin = current;
    var coincalcClass = new coincalculationClass();
    return coincalcClass.getHighLowForSpecificDays(coin.mktName, 3)
    .then(function(value) {
        var market_name = coin.mktName;
        var bestPrice = value['1'];
        addAlert('BTRX', market_name, bestPrice);
        return null; // appears as `previous` at next call
    });
}

recurseAsync(result[1], getCoinData, null, 1000);
```

Notes :

- `recurseAsync()` is conceptually similar to `Array#reduce()` but is written as a function not a method, and accepts a `minimumInterval` parameter (which defaults to 0).
- `previous` is not used in this example and is initialised with `null`.

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed explanation. This is great. I will be keeping it in my todo list. Regards,